# Set MySQL column collation in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collation

I need one of my MySQL tables to have different collation than the rest. Is it possible to set it in any clean way with Laravel 4? I found out it can be achieved this way:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('table', function($table) {});
```

Where `foo` is the name of separate connection with another collation. This solution is far from perfection, because I need to copy all connection config. Then, during migration, I need to remember to change it twice.

Is there any better way?